# How can I access my custom side indicators in Compare-Object in powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, compareobject

I am comparing two xml files that contain a record of directories and files that we want to update to be the same. I have custom messages that replace the "=>" and "<=" side indicators but in the file I export the object to I cannot see the messages or indicator column. When the names are very long is the side indicator put somewhere else? I just want to be able to see which file the difference comes from. This is what I see in the txt file I write it to.

```
  <Snapshots timestamp="10/19/2021 08:01:20">
  <Snapshots timestamp="10/26/2021 09:10:15">
      <Directory path="v195" />
      <File path="V169\seamless-mob-satinfo-v169" checksum="3857365E7BE8DB0933C57E17B69A250A7DD3A67C45A3F4E095E23797367E1BD6A7AF9F76FFF25B6016B9040C68561A8FF3076F4A195B89BAC74FEE7834106047" />
      <File path="v195\seamless-global-satinfo-v195" checksum="E68E8284A28C52EF43C447B446C31306D00FA1487CF9CDD630D39B507A403F18180210BA4B3F28218A501FFC2631BFD3D89A7F5C1A3CD0ABE09EB35DB806DD41" />
      <Directory path="A319\Version 7.10.1.58" />
      <File path="A319\Version 7.10.1.58\AAL_A319_4Wap_Production_7.10.1.58.tar.xz.enc" checksum="E44A154612CA668A720AB6AA57295832EB6D9B4A296A4410C73F6EF32165E0C3963CFA4922CF4CB4B50DC6F625BDEA0350BA2BFA30B42A274419C3908308C36E" />
      <Directory path="A321\Version 7.10.1.58" />
      <File path="A321\Version 7.10.1.58\AAL_A321_5Wap_Production_7.10.1.58.tar.xz.enc" checksum="39807D865C2429919A6F8635E82D12AB295313AF86F367EF43B6EC5A39620AE55F3764E5DCDDAF9448087BF8634776DCBBD9DACE7027458820DE432018DC09DC" />
      <Directory path="A321NX\Version 7.10.1.58" />
      <File path="A321NX\Version 7.10.1.58\AAL_A21N_5Wap_Production_7.10.1.58.tar.xz.enc" checksum="7059A222B8F14ECBE365157CBC24EC5573238A136B86446F3766B53EEF699DC86787C28EB246648866BAA20B28A3D6EFA59B5275CB31145E6E8BF35EAE2630D7" />
      <Directory path="B737MAX8\Version 7.10.1.58" />
      <File path="B737MAX8\Version 6.5.1.3\AAL_B38M_5Wap_Production_6.5.1.3.tar.xz.enc" checksum="06EB98A7D5993449B09707F730EBEBBA3F8E53731A9C8040D7298924F2427D8A72C14E61D8E43AB7477ECF7CEC4C5D67A1385DF95130D5C9141E6AF048AF42E3" />
      <File path="B737MAX8\Version 7.10.1.58\AAL_B38M_5Wap_Production_7.10.1.58.tar.xz.enc" checksum="7E83CF06AC84A16343149492ABDDF1893220AC109B079153A3E6905E4C8512DB22DFFDD08912ECE5B8C2CCF22CFF49814B5F8C97BB0164BF28826E0B918A19B2" />
      <Directory path="B737NG\Version 7.10.1.58" />
      <File path="B737NG\Version 7.10.1.58\AAL_B738_5Wap_Production_7.10.1.58.tar.xz.enc" checksum="DC4804FC8C030963BFF75B74431B5E680E403EEE92613FE620779692249C49AD58F056A4FCC557DF4B8EFBE6F1EBF165CF130D956428EBE8C20C5CD6EB504835" />
      <Directory path="B787\Version 7.5.1.9" />
      <File path="B787\Version 7.5.1.9\AAL_B788_6Wap_Production_7.5.1.9.tar.xz.enc" checksum="E68BE59CEA9C557B8AE42A1FA705DA5C5C5ACCE7124F60952DCD689689699A4A61CC162DC52D5AD24A9D867DF439D8204A8B1F1945A87681BB2EC06D17F9D012" />
      <File path="Version 7.10.1.79\system_software_load_kit_prod_7.10.1.79.tar" checksum="9E62D7C8EDDC736B9B4E03A1E70599DA3DE536E2A890091E038209B3C28FFAC3F49809FCF57BDCF29A1B09FB8F4332B136C3ADF3B6CFDDC1BEC7982219F43374" />
```

My code I am attempting this with is this.

```
$NAS = Get-Content C:\temp\Gold_Copy.xml
$Snapshot = Get-Content C:\temp\QJ07312433_10_19_2021_snapshot.xml

(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $NAS -DifferenceObject $Snapshot -PassThru |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '=>') {
            $_.SideIndicator = 'Not in NAS'
        } elseif ($_.SideIndicator -eq '<=')  {
            $_.SideIndicator = 'Not in Snapshot'
        }
        $_
    }) > C:\temp\diff.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object)'s `-PassThru` switch, which passes the (differing) input objects through as their original type, while *decorating* them with an instance `.SideIndicator` ETS `NoteProperty` property.

With *strings* as input objects, these decorations are *ignored* in many contexts, notably when you save to a file, such as with `>`.

You'll have to output the two pieces of information - the string value and the `.SideIndicator` value - *separately*.

You can repackage the values in a `[pscustomobject]` instance, which also allows you to put the side indicator into the first property, as shown in the following simplified example (note that there's then no strict reason to use `-PassThru` anymore):

```sh
Compare-Object ('foo', 'bar') ('foo', 'baz') -PassThru | 
  ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Source = @{ '=>' = 'Not in NAS'; '<=' = 'Not in snapshot'}[$_.SideIndicator]
      Line = $_
    }
  }
```

The above yields the following:

```
Source          Line
------          ----
Not in NAS      baz
Not in snapshot bar
```

Note that if you save this as-is to a file with `>`, you'll get exactly this *for-display* representation in the file.

Therefore, if you need to *programmatically process* the file later, it is better to use a *structured* text format such as CSV, for instance, by piping to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv).

Comment: Very thorough answer, thank you! Based on what you recommended I did this and it works exactly like I want it to.
Compare-Object $NAS $Snapshot -PassThru | 
    ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
        Source = @{ '=>' = 'Not in NAS'; '<=' = 'Not in snapshot'}[$_.SideIndicator]
        Line = $_
    }
    } | 
    Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\diff.csv

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @jakebake; my pleasure.